# Python equivalent of LINQ Single() function?

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, linq

I'm looking for equivalent of .NET Linq `IEnumerable.Single(predicate)` function in Python.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx

It is supposed to return exactly one element from enumerable/iterable that satisfy a condition and throw exception if there isn't exactly one element like that.

I know it can be easily coded by hand but I'm looking for something built-in.

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/472575/5311735